# getfilterable attributes returing empty in the magento backend

Tags: magento, attributes

I am trying to access get filterable attributes in the backend near system configuration values. Here is my code.

```
$layer = Mage::getModel("catalog/layer");
$layer->setCurrentCategory(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3));

print_r($layer->getFilterableAttributes()); 
exit;
```

Which returns empty array.

When I add this same code in the file outside magento directory I'm getting values.

Please Help Me